# How do Xavier's leg braces work in Wolverine & The X-Men?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine-and-the-x-men

Please note that this question is about the TV show *Wolverine & The X-Men*, not the comic of the same name.

When the show finally picks up with Professor Charles Xavier,

> he is in the future, having woken up from a long coma.

He is still unable to walk, apparently being paralyzed from the waist down as in most incarnations of the X-Men. He outfits himself with a pair of leg braces that appear to allow him to walk.

[image: xavier in his leg braces]

There seems to be no motorized mechanism, and this version of Xavier exhibits no telekinetic abilities. He is able to walk without assistance of any other mutant nearby (who might be using telekinesis for him).

Later in the show,

> Lorna Dane manipulates the braces, confirming that they are made of metal.

How do these braces allow him to walk, or how does he control them if he is paralyzed from the waist down?

Comment: Are we sure they're not motorized? I always thought that was it.

Comment: I'll have to try to get a better screencap, but I saw nothing on them that made me think they were motorized. Even if they were, with him being paralyzed from the waist down, it leaves the issue of how he controlled them.

Comment: Probably worth noting that paraplegics IRL can "walk" using braces, although it tends to be much more of a lurch, kind of like trying to walk on stilts using only your upper-body movement.

Comment: Pure speculation, but X-Men features plenty of machines that can interface with mental telepathy (e.g. Cerebro).  If I were designing braces for Xavier, I'd make them mechanical and directed by his mind.  In a sense, that's how real legs work anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Beast (Dr. Hank McCoy) is referenced by Charles several times in the show; it's possible that either him or Forge built the braces for Charles before being killed by the Sentinels.

Comment: The question was about how they operate, or are controlled - not who built them.

Comment: True, but if the braces were built by either Beast or Forge, then I'm sure they would have added a motor or battery of some sort.